# Construction by transfinite induction

Tags: set-theory

Théorème 2.1.6 (Construction by transfinite induction). Let $(X;\leq)$ be a well order, and $G$ a law which associates each function $g$ whose domain is a proper initial segment $X$ the element (ie, a set) $G(g)$. Then there exists a unique function $f$ of domain $X$ such that there is, for any $x \in X$, $f(x) = G(f \upharpoonleft X_{<x})$.

Can you explain the notation: $f(x) = G(f \upharpoonleft X_{<x})$. What does mean the half of upper arrow? Thanks!

Comment: I assume the term "good order" is supposed to be "well order"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow is the notation for the restriction of $f$. It means $\{\langle u,v\rangle\in f\mid u\in X_{<x}\}$.

So $f(x)$ has the same value as $G$ when applied to the initial segment defined by $x$.